# Google bot submitting random GET parameters

Tags: seo, googlebot

For some reason Google bot seems to be frequently hitting one of my dynamic pages sending %2letter% to a get parameter, ie. %zy%, %zn%, %xp%, %yu%, etc.

My access logs are filled with thousands of these entries where the Google bot is searching various combinations of 2 letters, some combos are sent many times. What is this behavior about?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your site is being indexed by a fake google bot. Here is the site with more information: http://stopmalvertising.com/security/fake-google-bots.html.

Also, check out the following article: [How to verify Googlebot](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html).